# How do you change the icon on far left of the menubar using Javafx 8?

Tags: java

I am developing an User Interface for a simulation application and would like to try and make the gui more professional by using my own application icon.

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Which OS do you work on?

Comment: If you work on `OS X` and use maven for your project, then just put your `icns` icon into the directory `src/main/deploy/myIcon.icns`. Then, you can use https://github.com/javafx-maven-plugin/javafx-maven-plugin plugin to build your application.

Answer (score 0):

Put your icon into the directory, e.g. `src/main/deploy/myIcon.icns`. Then deploy it as a native package (http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/self-contained-packaging.htm). You can make use of http://github.com/javafx-maven-plugin/javafx-maven-plugin plugin if you use maven to deploy your application.